# Android: Get Bluetooth SDP Service Name

Tags: android, bluetooth, sdp

The  Android Bluetooth API allows you to register an SDP service using:

```
String BLUETOOTH_NAME="MyBluetoothService";
mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BLUETOOTH_NAME, UUID.fromString(uuid));
```

It also allows you to initiate a Service Discovey on a remote Bluetooth Device to find the list of active service UUID's:

```
device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any public method available to get the service name. Can it be acquired by other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to get the names of services running on the device as you would do on a linux box with

sdptool browse local | egrep "Service Name:"

So the answer is no, as there is no Android API method and sdptool is not on android.

However you might write a c library containing an according function using the NDK and call the function via JNI (see Bluetooth for Programmers for the first on http://people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/BTBook.pdf).

By the way: Why do you want to list the services by name and not by UUID. It is my experience that service names slightly differ with implementations while UUIDS are credible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to do it this way because i wanna take advantage of the service name to pass along extra information (Like one would do with TXT records in a common networking scenario)